# Changes to PHP page not appearing in browser

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, caching

I've recently had an issue with my Wordpress (version 5.5 on Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7.2) website which meant I needed to restore from a backup and debug.

I restored an alternative version of one of my PHP pages from my dev site and executed it in the browser - it worked as expected and through the debugging console I realised where my issue was and went ahead and fixed it in the latest version of the file.

I then copied the "newest" PHP back into the directory and ran it in the browser.  The browser is still loading the "old" PHP page.

I assumed it was a caching issue, so I've cleared browser cache, tried different browsers, even different clients, disabled all caching plugins in Wordpress, restarted apache, confirmed Opcache is disabled, renamed the file - and as a last resort even removed the PHP file completely, and yet it still loads the old version in the browser!

Is there another server side caching mechanism I've overlooked?

-- EDIT -- I should add that I don't use a CDN either

Comment: Maybe restart apache?

Comment: Tried that already, no change

Comment: So, even if you remove everything, you don't get a 404 error? Can you also remove .htaccess ?

Comment: No, not removing everything, just the file I've been editing.  If I move the entire root directory, the site won't load.  I don't touch htaccess as it's managed by another process.

Comment: Yes, but the permalinks will change in that case

Comment: I've removed correct the htaccess and the site now fails to load. Moving it back and accessing the PHP page in question still loads the old page  (again, that page is acutally renamed so shouldn't even be loading).

Comment: What part of the content is cached ? and should be updated at the browser level ? Maybe the cache issue is not at the server side but at the cilent side. have you tried to open it in a private session ? another browser ?

Comment: All caching is definitely disabled - If I remove an image that loads in the PHP page, the image fails to load.   I've tried private broswer sessions, multiple browsers, and connecting via a different computer and mobile phone.